# Is there a way to parse a string in base r legend()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following function that I use to write the output of a lm into ggplot graphs:

```
lm_eqn <- function(df){ # GET EQUATION AND R-SQUARED AS STRING
  m <- lm(y ~ x, df);
  eq <- substitute("Y"[i] == a + b %.% italic("X"[i])*","~~italic(r)^2~"="~r2, 
                   list(a = format(unname(coef(m)[1]), digits = 2),
                        b = format(unname(coef(m)[2]), digits = 2),
                        r2 = format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 3)))
  as.character(as.expression(eq));
}

df = data.frame(x=1:100, y=runif(100, 0, 100))

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  annotate("text", x=50, y=50, label = lm_eqn(df), parse =TRUE)
```

It works perfectly well inside annotate if I use parse = TRUE. Unfortunately, the same procedure doesn't work in base r legend() because legend() has no parse operator.

```
m = lm(y ~ x, df)
plot(y ~ x, data=df)
abline(m)
legend("topright", legend = lm_eqn(df))
```

Is there a way to emulate annotate's behaviour in legend(), preferably using the same function?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `as.character` from the output of your function:

```r
lm_eqn <- function(df){ # GET EQUATION AND R-SQUARED AS STRING
  m <- lm(y ~ x, df);
  eq <- substitute("Y"[i] == a + b %.% italic("X"[i])*","~~italic(r)^2~"="~r2, 
                   list(a = format(unname(coef(m)[1]), digits = 2),
                        b = format(unname(coef(m)[2]), digits = 2),
                        r2 = format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 3)))
  as.expression(eq);
}

m = lm(y ~ x, df)
plot(y ~ x, data=df)
abline(m)
legend("topright", legend = lm_eqn(df))
```

[image]

This will also work in ggplot, you don't even need `parse = TRUE`

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  annotate("text", x=75, y=75, label = lm_eqn(df))
```

[image]

Comment: I get a warning from `annotate()` when I do that, apparently because it assumes the label is a character variable instead of an expression.  But it does work.

Comment: Did you remove parse = TRUE?

Comment: Yes, I did.  The warning was "is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'expression'".  I'm using ggplot2 v 3.3.5, which I think is current, but R v 4.1.0 patched, which isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your `lm_eqn` function so that it doesn't convert the result into a string at the end.  Then it will be fine:

```r
lm_eqn <- function(df){ # GET EQUATION AND R-SQUARED AS EXPRESSION
    m <- lm(y ~ x, df)
    eq <- substitute("Y"[i] == a + b %.% italic("X"[i])*","~~italic(r)^2~"="~r2, 
                                     list(a = format(unname(coef(m)[1]), digits = 2),
                                             b = format(unname(coef(m)[2]), digits = 2),
                                             r2 = format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 3)))
    as.expression(eq)
}

df = data.frame(x=1:100, y=runif(100, 0, 100))

m = lm(y ~ x, df)
plot(y ~ x, data=df)
abline(m)
legend("topright", legend = lm_eqn(df))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If you can't make changes to `lm_eqn`, then you could use `parse(text = lm_eqn(df))` instead; that's essentially what `annotate(parse=TRUE)` is doing.